# Adding time delay in Step Functions vs Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I need to write some endpoint that simulate the response of third party server to run performance test regularly. I have decided to go with API Gateway to Step Function (waits 2 seconds) to Lambda that returns response based on the request. This needs to be done to emulate latency of 2 seconds on third party service. The question is what would be the cheapest solution to solve the task using these services.

Should I go only with Lambda alone (no Step Functions and even API Gateway)? If I use only Lambda we would need many concurrent Lambdas each running for 2 seconds. What is the cheapest solution?

Comment: use step function for latency . Step function is an orchestration tool and designed to solve such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with AWS services and trying to work out pricing, you should use the [AWS Price Calculator](https://calculator.aws/). Each service also has pricing breakdowns:

- [AWS Step Functions Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/)
- [AWS Lambda Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)

Here's a quick work-up I did:

| Service | Price | Request/day | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lambda | $32/mo | 10k | 5 second runtime |
| Step Function | $76/mo | 10k | n/a |

From these numbers, the most cost effective solution would be to remove the Step Functions from the orchestration and just go with Lambdas.

A nice addition of using Lambdas are the ability to pass in a parameter to specify the 3rd party end-point latency. Or even a range or latency, i.e., random delay between 1 second and 3 seconds.

You can review this estimate [here](https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=b4ecc3ace1520c679ea36ee73e9d1709e5bec048).

Comment: Amazing service, thank you! Using the service I have made a calculation with a change that in case of using only lambda I would need concurrency enabled. So for example, if I make 100 requests per second to the lambda function that responds with a latency of 2 seconds I would need to have at least 200 concurrent lambdas. And that unfortunately gave me the result of paying much more than for a combination of these tools. Could you verify if I added the correct data? https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=d969d4199042b1f22942d3389e7ccc382d4c52c5

Comment: @JMas - Your cost estimate is so high because it includes lots of (always-ready, pre-warmed) [provisioned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html), which you definitely don't need for this DevOps task.

Comment: @fedonev is 100% correct. There is zero need to add any provisioned concurrency instances. The lambdas will spin up as-needed; once a lambda is done with a request, it will move on to another request; if it's busy, a new lambda will be spun up, and so-on. Read more: [Provisioned Concurrency Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#Provisioned_Concurrency_Pricing)

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. After tuning I found using both of the solutions considering there are 1 mln req per month cost the same price. Only lambda $4 whereas API gateway + step function + lambda cost the same $4.  https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=a31e77bcd6e9c1e0de4234175baf0ee850849d3c
Am I right on this calculation? If so I would go along with using lambda alone because of ease.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [SQS Delay Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) in front of the Lambda to simulate the 2 second latency.  The first million SQS messages are always free each month, the next million cost $0.40.

Your Lambdas will execute without any artificial delay, reducing your compute cost by (more than?) half.

Comment: The issue with it is there is a need to keep an http request, something should receive and then response in 2 seconds